# i cant convert an htaccess code to nginx conf code

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

i have an problem about this.
i tryed so many converters but that all not work.

i am write an video player script and this work like this with htaccess

http://127.0.0.1/myplayer/video/86dba86754c0ad93997a11fa947d97b2

(real path : player/includes/player.php?data=86dba86754c0ad93997a11fa947d97b2)

but there is another thing is have ajax post work on background like this

http://127.0.0.1/myplayer/video/86dba86754c0ad93997a11fa947d97b2?do=getVideo

(real path : player/includes/player.php?data=86dba86754c0ad93997a11fa947d97b2&do=getVideo)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)$ player/includes/player.php?data=$1&%1 [NC]
```

can someone convert this code for me ? i try so many days but is this not work. every time i get http error code. thanks alot! have a good day.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/myplayer/video/(.*)$ /player/includes/player.php?data=$1 last;`

Comment: thanks for your help, i got 500 Internal Server Error with this code

Comment: The error should appear in the error log with a more useful description.